# Can I submit form values using <input type="button" />?

Tags: php, ajax, post, button, get

I'm working on a search engine and I have a really serious problem with `GET` and `POST` methods.

Im using an `<input type="button" />` to avoid page from refreshing every time im pressing the button.

After button is pressed I'm showing a result (google_map, monumet picture, specs).

The problem now is that I want to submit and show form values + result (google_map, monumet picture, specs) by pressing this button.

This is a problem because `<input type="button" />` does not submit form values and I'm really stuck.

Comment: use javascript

document.getElementById("myform").submit();

Comment: <input id="slide" onMouseUp="getScriptPage('count_display','text_content','1')" type="button"
style="font-family:cursive;border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;background-color:brown;color:white;font-size:14pt;"  value="Search now" 
name="filter"    />  <BR/><BR/>

Comment: the problem is that i already using javascript if button isset onMouseUp="getScriptPage('count_display','text_content','1')"

Comment: is it possible to call to javascript functions the same time ? onMouseUp="getScriptPage('count_display','text_content','1'); script_page2(.....);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here is a working example for you:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Working Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="search-form">
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" value=""><br>
    <input type="button" id="search-button" name="search-button" value="search">
</form>

<div id="response"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-button').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                type: "GET",
                url: 'response.php',
                data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#response').html(response);
                }
            } );
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php

echo "text1: " . $_GET['text1'] . "<br>";
echo "text2: " . $_GET['text2'] . "<br>";
echo "text3: " . $_GET['text3'] . "<br>";

echo "your response ...";
```

In the response you return whatever your response is, plus the form fields.

Comment: thanks arielcr,can you please post me a working example with this code you just post to me? coz i tried my self and i think im doing something wrong

Comment: I edit the answer with a working example. I forgat to tell you that you can use whatever event for the ajax response, I used the click event for the button as a example. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you so much you are the best...you save my day for sure ...:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick="document.getElementById('FormName').submit();"
```

Comment: im already using onMouseUp="getScriptPage('count_display','text_content','1')"......Can i use onclick and onMouseUp in the same input?

Comment: @AntreasApostolou It would take less to to try it yourself then writing this comment...